# Regex path matching in chaotic input

Tags: regex

I have some chaotic log output which looks something like below (yes those weird new lines actually exist at those place. :)

```
C:\testing\testpath\testfile.txt
\\1.2.3.4\c$\test\testpath1\testpath2\k
\\1.2.3.4\c$\test\testpath1\testpath2\
C:\ro\row\rou\line.txt:line 234
Failed to grant AssetID=33683041 to UserID=44129434: Recipient already owns Asset at Corp.UserAsset.AwardUserAsset(Int6
4 assetReferenceId, Int32 userId, Boolean preventDuplicates, Boolean& awardedNewAsset) 
in d:\workspace\Trunk\Assemblies\SCL\CCL\BLL\UserAsset.cs:line 723 at Corp.UserAsset.AwardUserAsset(Int64 assetReferenceId, Int32 userId, Boolean preventDuplicates) in d:\workspace\Trunk\Assemblies\SCL\CCL\BLL\UserAsset.cs:line 710 at Corp.Website.Badge.Award.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in d:\workspace\Trunk\Web\CorpWebSite\Badge\Award.ashx.cs:line 111 at  System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

What I would like to get out of the regex is something like this:

```
C:\testing\testpath\testfile.txt
\\1.2.3.4\c$\test\testpath1\testpath2\k
\\1.2.3.4\c$\test\testpath1\testpath2\
C:\ro\row\rou\line.txt:line 234
d:\workspace\Trunk\Assemblies\SCL\CCL\BLL\UserAsset.cs:line 723 at Corp.UserAsset.AwardUserAsset(Int64 assetReferenceId, Int32 userId, Boolean preventDuplicates) in
d:\workspace\Trunk\Assemblies\SCL\CCL\BLL\UserAsset.cs:line 710 at Corp.Website.Badge.Award.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in
d:\workspace\Trunk\Web\CorpWebSite\Badge\Award.ashx.cs:line 111 at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I currently have the following regex

```
([\w]:\\|\\\\)([^\r\n]*)
```

but the result is not quite there I am getting the first 4 lines but the last error line just comes out as a single line instead of 3.
and I am wondering even if what I need can be done with a single regex.

Comment: Ouch: the need to match backslashes makes a hard job even harder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one:

```
([\w]:\\|\\\\)(([^\r\n](?!([\w]:\\|\\\\)))*)
```

I added a negative look-ahead (`(?!...)`) right after `[^\r\n]` to prevent it from keep matching if your starting pattern is met again. I find it the most straightforward from what you already got.

Check the result: http://regexr.com?35mjh

Comment: Did you get to try this one out?

Comment: Sorry got distracted with other work. ;) The result is much better however I need to have the regex stop after the digits ( line XXXX) in the last lines.

Comment: How about this one: `([\w]:\\|\\\\)(([^\r\n](?!([\w]:\\|\\\\|at)))*)` ? http://regexr.com?35p59

Comment: first 3 lines are no longer complete sorry

Comment: How bout this: `([\w]:\\|\\\\)(([^\r\n](?!([\w]:\\|\\\\|at )))*)` http://regexr.com?35q2q